# How to simplify this Game of Life method that counts the number of neighbors a cell has?

Tags: java, simplify, conways-game-of-life

This method checks if the cell is an edge cell (on a border) and then counts how many live neighbors it has. The value is then returned and used to determine if that cell lives or dies. This takes a lot of space and looks pretty ugly. Is there a way I can do all of this in a lot fewer lines?

```
// takes in board and checks a cell's neighbors, returning the number of living neighbors
// checks if a cell is on a border, therefore causing it to have less neigbors
public static int checkNeighbors(int[][] board, int i, int j)
{
    int count = 0;   // live neighbors of cell will be added here

    if(i - 1 < 0 && j - 1 < 0)   // in top left corner, only three neighbors
    {
        if(board[i][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(i - 1 < 0 && j + 1 > width - 1)   // in top right corner, only three neighbors
    {
        if(board[i][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(i + 1 > height - 1 && j - 1 < 0)   // in bottom left corner, only three neighbors
    {
        if(board[i][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(i + 1 > height - 1 && j + 1 > width - 1)   // in bottom right corner, only three neighbors
    {
        if(board[i][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(j - 1 < 0)   // on left border, only five neighbors
    {
        if(board[i - 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(j + 1 > width - 1)   // on right border, only five neighbors
    {
        if(board[i - 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(i - 1 < 0)   // on top border, only five neighbors
    {
        if(board[i][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else if(i + 1 > height - 1)   // on bottom border, only five neighbors
    {
        if(board[i][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    else   // cell is not on any border, has full eight neighbors
    {
        if(board[i - 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i - 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j - 1] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j] == 1)
            count++;
        if(board[i + 1][j + 1] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

StackOverflow is telling me to add more details because my post is mostly code. I dont think any more details are required so I am typing this down here just to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your check into one place:

```
public static int countNeighbours(int[][] board, int i, int j) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
            if ((x != 0 || y != 0) && checkCell(board, i + x, j + y)) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static boolean checkCell(int[][] board,int x, int y) {
    return (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height && board[x][y] == 1);
}
```

You could do something even shorter with Streams, but this is clearer if you aren't familiar with them.

Comment: You got my very last edit? I had a bug until that.

Comment: I noticed that it is currently not making a dead cell turn alive when it has exactly three neighbors. Im not sure if that is due to other parts of my code or this. I'll check with the edits.

Comment: with the edit, everything is now working as it should. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```java
for (int y = i-1; y <= i+1; i1++){//loop around point on outer array (y-axis on classic 2D coordinate system)
    for (int x = j-1; x <= j+1; x++) {//loop around point on inner array (x-axis on classic 2D coordinate system)
        if (i==y&&j==x) {
            continue;//same case-->skip
        }
        //option 1
        if(y<0||y>board.length||x<0||x>board[x].length){
            continue;//outside-->skip
        }
        //option 2
//      int otherCellX=y%board.length;//if > length -->start again on other side
//      int otherCellY=x%board[0].length;
//      if (y<0) {//if < 0-->go to end
//          otherCellX+=board.length;
//      }
//      if (x<0) {
//          otherCellY+=board[otherCellX].length;
//      }
        if (board[otherCellX][otherCellY]==1) {//if alive, increment count
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

This loops over the points around the current cell.

It tests if it is the same cell or a cell out of the board. If it is not and the cell is alive, it will add 1 to the count.

In option 2, if it is outside the board, it takes the number on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the indeces are out of bounds or are equal to your `i,j` parameter and skip them if so. Otherwise, add them to your `counter`.

```
public static int checkNeighbors(int[][] board, int i, int j) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1; row++) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= board.length) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int column = j - 1; column <= j + 1; column++) {
            if (column < 0 || column >= board[row].length || (row == i && column == j)) {
                continue;
            }
            counter += board[row][column];
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```